# Use Linq to move item to bottom of list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

This is my code:

```
var list = from c in child_categories orderby c.Translated_Syntax 
           select new { Name = c.Translated_Syntax, ID = c.ID_Category } ;

lst_category.DataSource = list;    
lst_category.DataBind();
```

My list of categories is: Car, Other, Children, House, Girl, Show.

If I order my list, the result it will be:

- Car
- Children
- Girl
- Other
- Show

But I want the 'Other' item to be placed to bottom of list. 
Something like this:

- Car
- Children
- Girl
- Show
- Other

How can I do this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use this `Orderby`-"trick":

```
from c in child_categories 
orderby c.Translated_Syntax == "Other", c.Translated_Syntax
```

You can remember how it works in this way: the comparison returns a `bool` where `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`. That's why `orderby Translated_Syntax == "Other"` will list the "Others" last. If you want it to precede you either have to reverse the condition or (better) use `descending` instead.

Comment: Can this be achieved using the function syntax ?

Comment: @fripp13: sure: `var q=child_categories.OrderBy(c => c.Translated_Syntax == "Other").ThenBy(c => c.Translated_Syntax)`